# Corona: How to scale an Image after I created it

Tags: image, lua, scale, coronasdk

I created an Image here:

```
gangster = display.newImageRect("assets/gangsta.png", gangsterwidth, gangsterheight)
gangster.x = display.contentCenterX
gangster.y = 950
sceneGroup:insert(gangster)
```

And I want to scale the Image now after I set it here:

```
local function enterFrameListener()
    if holding then
       if ( touchx < gangster.x) then
          gangster.x = gangster.x - 10

        end
           if ( touchx > gangster.x) then
          gangster.x = gangster.x + 10

        end
               if ( touchy > gangster.y) then
          gangster.y = gangster.y + 10
          -- INCREASE HEIGHT AND WIDTHHERE

        end
               if ( touchy < gangster.y) then
          gangster.y = gangster.y - 10
           gangsterheight = gangsterheight -5
          -- DECREASE HEIGHT AND WIDTH HERE

        end
         if (touchx == gangster.x) then
          if (touchy == gangster.y) then
         Runtime:removeEventListener( "enterFrame", enterFrameListener)
         holding = false
         end
       end
    else
    end
end
```

But how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Display objects have a scale method. In your case, you should just be able to do

```
gangster:scale(0.5,0.5) -- half the size
```

Comment: Omg I'm so silly I always forger using : instead of . . Thank you!